# How to go to beginning of command in term mode in Emacs?

Tags: bash, emacs

I am running bash terminal under `Term: line run` mode inside Emacs.

Often I want to go to beginning of a command (not beginning of line, which includes the prompt). 
i.e. In below line, I 'd like to go to `s` (not `p`).

`prompt> some command text here`

May I know what is the key shortcut in doing so, if any?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd> (`term-bol`) is intended to do this. It works by moving to the beginning of the line, and then skipping forward past the prompt, as defined by the buffer-local `term-prompt-regexp` variable.

However the default value for that regex is just `^` (which therefore has no effect in this situation); so you would need to set it yourself. There are some useful examples in that variable's help text.

Some alternative options are:

- Use `term-char-mode` instead (in which case <kbd>C-a</kbd> works).
  You can switch to char mode with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd> and back to line mode with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd>.
- Copy that same binding for <kbd>C-a</kbd> for `term-line-mode`, so that it does the same thing in both modes:

  ```
  (define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-a") 'term-send-raw)
  ```
- Create a new binding which does the same thing. e.g.:

  ```
  (define-key term-mode-map (kbd "s-a") (lambda () (interactive) (term-send-raw-string (string 1))))
  ```

  n.b. Using `(string 1)` because `C-a` is ascii value 1. See the definition of `term-send-raw`.

Comment: I tried to set `term-prompt-regexp` using either `set-variable` or `customize-variable`. However neither could find a match to this var name. Are you sure this is the correct name?

Comment: `set-variable` and `customize-variable` only see the so-called "user option" variables. If the term library is loaded then you should be able to see this var using `C-h v`. Set a default value in code using `(setq-default term-prompt-regexp "^...")` -- as term-mode makes it buffer-local -- or use `term-mode-hook` to set the buffer-local value with `setq`.

Comment: Personally I feel that getting used to using `term-char-mode` by default (and only switching modes when necessary) is a good approach. It's nice that this prompt regexp exists, but it would probably require a lot of effort to make it automatically reliable in all situations, unless your terminal usage is very limited (e.g. you only ever run a shell in your Emacs terminals, and you never run other interactive programs from those shells. Outside of those constraints, a single default value is unlikely to suffice).

Comment: thanks a lot for the clarification. I will try it out. The reason why I favored line mode was because of heavy usage complex expressions in interpreters. e.g. I entered parenthesized expressions which I feel a little easier to navigate through using Emacs key-bindings which is only available in line-mode.